# No right click, No icons on desktop, Icons are in the taskbar instead?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, taskbar, desktop-icons

My service laptop, running on XP for the moment, do not display any icon on the desktop nor allow to right click on the desktop.
The desktop icons are instead located in the taskbar, I deleted the registry key : HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/Current Version/Policies/explorer/NoDesktop.
Thanks for your help.

Guillaume.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your laptop is protected to use the desktop by group policy or other method. Is it your laptop and/or are you allowed to make these changes? If a group policy is enforced through a domain controller, it will be impossible to bypass this. If you log in locally and you may do everything you want with the laptop, disabling/altering the group policy should be the first thing to do. Note that if you are not supposed to do this, you will get some angry eyes on you.